# Excel web access webpart throwing javascript error ( in ewamoss.js) in IE10

Tags: excel-services, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

I am using Excel web access web part  to display Excel reports in Sharepoint 2010. It's working fine with IE9. When I am loading the report in IE 10, it's throwing the error  "Unable to get property 'PermissionFlagsHash' of undefined or null reference " in  ewamoss.js file.

Comment: What about in compatibility mode?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in IE10 compatibility view also..But it's working when i change the browser mode to IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how i missed closing this, this issue has been resolved with product updates. Now working fine on Edge as well

Answer (score 1):

Currently, IE 10 (release preview) is not supported in SP 2010.

In the meantime, try this. Press F12, to bring up the developer tools. In the Script tab, debug ewamoss.js file to see why you are getting a null reference.

[Supported browsers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288142%28office.12%29.aspx)